# What does this mean Vote casts?

Tags: discussion

Can some body tell me what the picture mean ?

[image]

does it mean user has upvoted 158 times and 385 times downvoted then what is by type ?

Answer (score 2):

> does it mean user has upvoted 158 times and 385 times downvoted

Yes.

> what is by type ?

"by type" shows on how many questions/answers you have voted. "445 question" means that the user has voted on 445 questions, and "98 answer" means that the user has voted on 98 answers.